# Django REST Framework: How to use prefetched queriesets in child serializers in nested serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to call a queryset prefetched from a View from a nested serializer child.
I tried the following but it did not work the way I intended.
How can I call a prefetched queryset from a child serializer?

```py
#models.py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
   ...

#This is allauth.models
class EmailAddress(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        allauth_app_settings.USER_MODEL,
        verbose_name=_("user"),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    verified = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_("verified"), default=False)
```

```py
#views.py
class PlaylistListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PlaylistSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return (
            Playlist.objects.all()
            .prefetch_related("user", "user__emailaddress_set")
        )

#serializers.py
class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_verified = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("is_verified",)

    def get_is_verified(self, user):
        return user.emailaddress_set.filter(verified=1).count() > 0 # <- here


class PlaylistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserDetailSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Playlist
        fields = ("user",)
```

[function max(boolean) does not exist: error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsW3t.png)

Comment: Is it the query run in `UserDetailSerializer.get_is_verified` that you want to be prefetched?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `Prefetch` object to prefetch the users with an annotation for if it is verified or not, `verified` seems to be a boolean so selecting the `Max` will give us `True` if any related emails are verified. In the serializer we can then look for this annotation and if it exists return it otherwise return the same thing as before

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch, Max


class PlaylistListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PlaylistSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Playlist.objects.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('user', queryset=User.objects.annotate(_is_verified=Max('emailaddress__verified')))
        )


class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_verified = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("is_verified",)

    def get_is_verified(self, user):
        if hasattr(user, "_is_verified"):
            return user._is_verified
        else:
            return user.emailaddress_set.filter(verified=True).exists()
```

Comment: An error occurred: `function max(boolean) does not exist`.
Also, the UserDetailSerializer will be the one called from the PlaylistSerializer, but
Is it called and prefetched exactly as I surrendered it?

Comment: Where is that error being raised? Might be an issue with the name of the annotation, try renaming it, updated my answer

Comment: There was a problem with the annotation name.
I've added models.py to the question, and the relationship between user and emailaddress looks like this The only way I can figure out is to call it by reverse reference. Is it impossible to call it by reverse reference in annotation? It says `Cannot resolve keyword 'emailaddress_set' into field.`
`Prefetch("user", queryset=User.objects.annotate(is_verified=Max("emailaddress_set__verified"))`

Comment: No, you need to use `emailaddress` in the prefetch, you don't include `_set` when traversing a reverse relationship in queries. Try naming the annotation "_is_verified" like in the updated answer?

Comment: I'm still getting the `function max(boolean) does not exist` error.
Please see the image added to the question for more details.

Comment: Ah, which DB are you using? Might have to cast the boolean to an int?`Prefetch('user', queryset=User.objects.annotate(_is_verified=Max(Cast('emailaddress__verified', output_field=IntegerField()))))`

Comment: Thank you! I was able to solve this successfully.
Also, this gives me a value of `1` for validated.
Should I use `When, Case` to make it a Boolean?

Comment: Could `Cast` it again, or just convert it in the method `return bool(user._is_verified)`